# Firebird 1.5 : Nested Aggregation

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a SQL statement needed to use more than 1 aggregate functions in Firebird, but I am getting below error :

```
Error: GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Nested aggregate and window functions are not allowed
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 335544569
```

This is my sample SQL :

```
SELECT SUM(LOG(3, (NoPassed/TotalNo * 100))) FROM TABLE_A
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: That kind of aggregating is not possible in most dbmses. Tell us what are you trying to achieve..

Comment: @AndrejKirejeŭ, it is not possible to FB 2.5 because it needs to undergo long process before we could do that, and currently the company have no plan to do the upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill in a temp table with results of LOG function and then execute SUM aggregate function.

1)

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP (S DOUBLE PRECISION)
```

2)

```
INSERT INTO TEMP (S)
SELECT LOG(3, (NoPassed/TotalNo * 100)) FROM TABLE_A
```

3)

```
SELECT SUM(S) FROM TEMP
```